# Setting field value in AppMaker in validation script

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I have a probably very basic question on Google AppMaker. A number input field in a form only accepts numbers with "dot" decimal separator. Yet the users normally use a "comma" as decimal separator. So I am trying to catch the entered value during validation and to format it correctly. I use the onValidate event and format the newValue. So far so good. I just cannot figure out how to write the corrected value back to the original form field so the record can be written. Can anyone direct me on the syntax of how to assign the new Value back to the form field? Thx.

[This is the "code" situation...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nva3M.png)

Comment: If post your code (minimal example) probably more people will be interested in posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if anyone cares; made it work by using

**widget.datasource.item.JobCharge** = number;